# How to limit Google Cloud VM Access to wifi domain

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ip, firewall

I'm trying to limit ssh access to a google cloud vm instance by using the firewall in "VPC Network". I only want to be able to access the vm when I'm on my university's wifi. I've added the DNS server IP addresses (listed here: https://accc.uic.edu/service/uic-net) but once I add them to the firewall I lose access even when I'm on them.

[snapshot of firewall impl](https://imgur.com/a/cz34urH)

*I've even tried using my specific machine IP address with no luck (even though I want the whole network to have access, not just my machine)

Answer (score 0):

Adding the DNS server IP address to a Google VPC firewall rule will not enable access from your network. You need to know your network's public IP CIDR block and use that for the firewall.

From the document link that you provided, your network is using two netblocks: 131.193.0.0/16 and 128.248.0.0/16. Verify that the network you are connecting within uses one of these CIDR blocks. Go to any website that supports "What is my IP" such as https://www.whatismyip.com/

Then create a firewall rule specifying:

- Direction of traffic: Ingress
- Action on match:
- Allow Source filter: IP ranges
- Source IP ranges: 131.193.0.0/16, 128.248.0.0/16
- Protocols and ports: Allow all

Comment: I've tried updating my firewall with your specifications, but I'm still unable to connect. I have confirmed that my ip begins with 128.248 so I don't see why the change wouldn't work. https://imgur.com/a/evZvvfY

Comment: What are you connecting with? What error is being reported? Can you ping the instance?

Comment: I'm connecting via the ssh button ( https://imgur.com/a/tTCYEbX ) . It launches a window with a vm instance that the ssh key connects with. The error I get is generic; it says it's unable to connect on port 22.

Comment: Can you ping the public IP address of the instance? Is your school blocking port 22?

Comment: Yes, if I set the IP filter to 0.0.0.0/0 (ie allow all traffic) I'm able to connect via port 22

Comment: If you can access it using 0.0.0.0/0 but not using the CIDR blocks, then you are not specifying the correct CIDR block in the firewall rule. Is your school using a proxy?